# remove formatting from html editor

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a html editor and i want when anyone copy paste content into editor it remove all     formatting ,extra html,css which apply automatically pasted content.it is use in my asp.net website

Comment: We can't read your thoughts or your screen. Please be more specific, post what you have tried and how it failed, the you might get help...

Comment: You can use regular expressions to remove html tags along with attributes(css)

Answer (score 2):

Try **Regex.Replace**

```
//// To remove all HTML tags    
string pattern = @"<.*?>";

//// If you want to keep some tags(Eg:<p>,<b>) you can use a pattern like
string pattern = @"<([/]{0,1}(!--|p|b))(.|\n)*?>";

Regex.Replace(inputHtml, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```